# How to make text stay large using responsive classes

Tags: tailwind-css

I want my header to stay large at all times. Heres my code.

```
 <h1 className='main-title  sm:text-4xl md:text-5xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-5xl font-bold '>
```

Men i minimise the screen the text goes to a small size and doesn't stay large.

Comment: What is `'className'`? Shouldn't it be just `'class'`?

Comment: I'm using React so its JSX. You have to say className instead of class. I should of specified in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Tailwind uses a mobile first breakpoint system.

```
<h1 class='main-title text-4xl md:text-5xl font-bold' />
```